# The $L^{2}-$extension construction of Ito integral in several literature

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am learning the $L^{2}-$extension of Ito integral, and in the construction of extension, Karatzas and Shreve (and some online notes) seemed to analyze such a class of functions:

> Let the "probability space" be $([0,T],\mathcal{B}, Leb)$, so we are just analyzing the usual lebesgue integral, etc.
>
> Let $f\in L^{2}([0,T],\mathcal{B}, Leb)$ and for al $h>0$, we define a kind of averaging as follows: 
>   $$f_{h}(t)=\left\{
>              \begin{array}{ll}
>              0, \ \ \ 0\leq t<h;\\
>              \\
>              \dfrac{1}{h}\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)ds,\ \ \ kh\leq t<(k+1)h\wedge T.
>              \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> Then, the literature claims that $\|f_{h}\|_{L^{2}}\leq\|f\|_{L^{2}}$ and $f_{h}$ converges to $f$ in $L^{2}$ as $h\rightarrow 0$.

The only thing I can derive from this definition is using Jensen's inequality to obtain:$$|f_{h}(t)|^{2}\leq\dfrac{1}{h^{2}}\Big|\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh\wedge T}f(s)ds\Big|^{2}\leq\dfrac{1}{h^{2}}\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh\wedge T}f(s)^{2}ds\leq\dfrac{1}{h^{2}}\|f\|_{L^{2}}.$$

What is exactly the $L^{2}$ norm of $f_{h}(t)$? When I integrate $f_{h}(t)^{2}$ over $t\in [0,T]$, then value of $f_{h}(t)$ changes given different $kh\leq t<(k+1)h\wedge T$....

What can I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will show the bound : For given $h>0$, let $\tilde{f}(s):=f(sh)$. Then
$$||f_h||_{L^2}^2=\int_0^Tf_h^2\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor}h\bigg(\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor}h\bigg(\int_{k-1}^k\tilde{f}\bigg)^2\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor}h\int_{k-1}^k\tilde{f}^2$$$$=h\int_0^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor}\tilde{f}^2=h\int_0^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor h}f^2h^{-1}=\int_0^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor h}f^2\leq ||f||_{L^2}^2.$$
EDIT : I add the $L^2$ convergence result. First, suppose $f$ is continuous. If we fix $t\in [0,T]$, then $\forall h>0$, $\exists k=k(h)$ s.t. $kh\leq t<(k+1)h$.  For such $k$, $$|f_h(t)-f(t)|\leq h^{-1}\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}|f(s)-f(t)|ds\leq\max_{(k-1)h\leq s\leq kh}|f(s)-f(t)|\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow 0}0$$ by continuity of $f$. Therefore $f_h\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow 0} f$, $\forall f\in C([0,T])$.  Now let $f\in L^2([0,T])$. Take any $\epsilon>0$, and since $C^\infty$ is dense in $L^2$, we have $g\in C^\infty([0,T])$ such that $||g-f||_{L^2}<\epsilon/3$. Therefore $$||f_h-f||_{L^2}\leq ||f_h-g_h||_{L^2}+||g_h-g||_{L^2}+||g-f||_{L^2}\leq||g_h-g||_{L^2}+2||g-f||_{L^2}$$ $$\leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{2\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon,$$ by taking $h$ small enough. (used $||g_h-f_h||_{L^2}=||(g-f)_h||_{L^2}\leq||g-h||_{L^2}$)

EDIT2 : I will show how did I obtain the first inequality of the first part, as detail as possible. Note that  $T\leq(\lfloor T/h\rfloor +1)h$, hence $k=\lfloor T/h\rfloor$ is last $k$ possible for given $h>0$. Then, 
$$\int_0^Tf_h^2=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor-1}\int_{kh}^{(k+1)h}f^2_h\bigg)+\underbrace{\int_{\lfloor T/h\rfloor h}^{T}f^2_h}_{\text{term for }k=\lfloor T/h\rfloor,\text{ but the integral ends at }T}$$

$$=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor-1}\int_{kh}^{(k+1)h}\bigg(\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2\bigg)+\int_{\lfloor T/h\rfloor h}^{T}\bigg(\int_{(\lfloor T/h\rfloor-1)h}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor h}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2$$

$$=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor-1}\bigg(\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2\int_{kh}^{(k+1)h}dt\bigg)+\bigg(\int_{(\lfloor T/h\rfloor-1)h}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor h}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2\int_{\lfloor T/h\rfloor h}^{T}dt$$

$$=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor-1}\bigg(\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2h\bigg)+\bigg(\int_{(\lfloor T/h\rfloor-1)h}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor h}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2(T-\lfloor T/h\rfloor h).$$

And since

$$T-\lfloor T/h\rfloor h\leq h,$$

$$\int_0^Tf_h^2\leq\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor-1}\bigg(\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2h\bigg)+\bigg(\int_{(\lfloor T/h\rfloor-1)h}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor h}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2h$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor T/h\rfloor}\bigg(\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)h^{-1}ds\bigg)^2h.$$

Maybe this was not so trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to apply your method to show the convergence but failed.. do you know how to show the convergence?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Observe pointwise convergence and apply dominated convergence.

Comment: Would you mind writing a proof?..thank you! I can open a bounty for you if you want :)

Comment: @JacobsonRadical That’s very nice of you, but Im on bed now, so if you can wait then I can add more detail on this post when Im awake and hopefully get to the PC.

Comment: yeah please do so :) I am also going to bed now. have a good night. But the way I need $L^{2}$ convergence.. for unknown reason I just got so confused to this averaging function.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Sorry for late, I add the convergence result.

Comment: WOW. Brilliant answer. I got it, it makes sense. Let me firstly accept your answer, and how about we wait for 1 more day so that I can open a bounty for you. Thank you for your nice answer :)

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Haha, thanks but it's alright for the bounty. Good luck.

Comment: By the way, as my understanding of your proof, does it mean $f_{h}(t)$ can be written as $$f_{h}(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{[T/h]}\Big(\dfrac{1}{h}\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)ds\Big)\mathbb{1}_{[kh,(k+1)h\wedge T)}(t)?$$

Comment: @JacobsonRadical No. $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is biggest integer such that smaller than $x$. The first Inequality (of the first part) holds because we are ignoring the edge part : $T<s<(\lfloor T/h\rfloor+1) h$.

Comment: so the extra $h$ that multiplied to $\Big(\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)h^{-1}ds\Big)^{2}$ is due to this ignoring?

Comment: Actually, yes to the expression above in the comment. Sorry, I did not see the charicteristic function part. And $h$ is multiplied since $h=|\chi_{[kh,(k+1)h)}|$, so yes, you are right.

Comment: never mind, I understand and will stick to your proof. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: wait... I am sorry for coming back and forth about this integral, this is where my confusion is. If the formula is the right, then would it be $$\int_{0}^{T}f_{h}(t)dt=\int_{0}^{T}\sum_{k=1}^{[T/h]}\dfrac{1}{h}\int_{(k-1)h}^{kh}f(s)ds\mathbb{1}_{[kh, (k+1)h\wedge T)}(t)dt?$$

Comment: would you mind elaborating a little bit about how you get the first integral bound and what is exactly the integral of $f_{h}(t)$? Thank you so so much.......

Comment: WOW. I definitely absolutely and surely need to give you bounty... wow.. brilliant!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added the detail. Indeed this may needed more explanations.

Comment: Thank you so much!